# Vue DataTable with Date Range Picker to Filter Dates

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, datatable, daterangepicker

I have Vue DataTable in thymeleaf template using Spring Boot and I want to implement Date Range Picker to filter the data by Start & End Date. The following is DataTable html page.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="dateRangePicker"></input> -->
</div>
<script>    
        var logTable= new Vue({
            el: "#logTable",
            data: {
                id: "logTB",
                title: "[[#{label_logTable}]]",
                headers: [
                    { name: "[[#{label_time}]]", className: "sort pr-1 align-middle text-center" },
                    { name: "[[#{label_name}]]", className: "sort pr-1 align-middle text-center" },
                    { name: "[[#{label_log}]]", className: "sort pr-1 align-middle text-center" },
                ],
                configs: { searchDelay: 1000, serverSide: true, processing: true, ajaxDataProp: "data",
                    ajax: parentUrl = contextPath + "rest/logs",
                    columns: [
                        {   data: "id", defaultContent: "", className: "text-center", orderable: false,
                        },
                        { data: "time", defaultContent: "", className: "align-middle text-center" },
                        { data: "name", defaultContent: "", className: "align-middle text-center" },
                        { data: "log", defaultContent: "", className: "align-middle text-center" },
                    ]
                }
            },
            methods: {

            },
            computed: {

            },
            mounted() {

            }
        });
    </script>
```

I have Date Range Picker function to select Start & End Date in another html page as follows.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.dateRangePicker').daterangepicker({
            'autoApply' : false,
            'autoUpdateInput': false,
            "showDropdowns": true,
            "linkedCalendars": false,
            'showCustomRangeLabel' : true,
            'opens': 'right',
            'startDate': moment().subtract(3, 'month'),
            'endDate': moment(),
            'ranges' : {
                'Today' : [moment(), moment()],
                'This Week' : [moment().startOf('week').add(1, 'days'), moment().endOf('week').add(1, 'days')],
                'This Month' : [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'This Year' : [moment().startOf('year'), moment().endOf('year')]
            },
            locale : {
                'format': 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                ,'separator': "   -   "
                ,'applyLabel': 'Apply'
                ,"cancelLabel": 'Cancel'
                ,'customRangeLabel': 'Custom Range'
            }
        }, function(start, end, label) {
            $('.dateRangePicker').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '   -   ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            url = parentUrl + '?startDate=' + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '&endDate=' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            logTable.ajax.url(url).load;
    });
});
</script>
```

Finally, URL with Start & End Date is passed to Spring Rest Controller.

```
@JsonView(DataTablesOutput.View.class)
@GetMapping("/rest/logs")
public DataTablesOutput<Log> listAllLogs(@RequestParam(value = "startDate", required = false) String startDate, @RequestParam(value = "endDate", required = false) String endDate, DataTablesInput input) {     
    //Call Filter Function 
}
```

Final result I have is a textbox for selecting date as defined like Today, This Week and so on. Once the date is selected, it is displayed in the textbox. However, the URL is not passed to Rest Controller and table is not reloaded to reflect the changes.